# Nested Routes in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-router, react-redux

I'm not sure how to get either a nested route to display two components at the same time or even two non nested routes to display two components at the same time.

My routing looks like:

```
export default (    
    <Route path="/" component={Index}>
        <Route path="/nextpage" component={Index2} />
    </Route>
);
```

which gets utilized within my provider

```
export default (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

I'm new to react, but my understanding is that when I visit endpoint nextpage, that both Index and Index2 should be rendered. However, only the first component is rendered. Is there anything else I have to do to make both components appear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every child of `Route` is going to be available as `props.children`.

When you are at `/`, `Index` is going to be rendered with `props.children` being empty.

When you are at `/nextpage`, `Index` is going to be rendered as well, but this time `props.children` contains `Index2`.

So, in `Index` you have to think about where you want to render `props.children`.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe I missed something so simple.